# MVC app is rending a view instead of entire page (specific install)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I had to set up an asp.net mvc 1 site on someone's laptop today.

For some reason there was a particular page that when you click a button - it uses javascript/jquery to call an mvc action/controller that returns content.  It is then supposed to update part of the page with the results.  Instead it was rendering the page as only the view that should have been updated (not the main page that contains the view).  ie. you enter search criteria and click filter - and it is supposed to update the div containing a list of search results.  Instead of the page looking normal - it displayed the search results only - with no css applied to it.

It only happens on this machine (had tried copying across my local files and my database but still got errors) - and only happens in IE 8.  In Firefox it works fine.  Similar functionality in an earlier version was also set up as a different site on the same machine - and that works fine in IE.  ie. clicking that button in the different local site worked fine.  Which is weird if it had been a browser setting that was causing the difference then you wouldn't expect it to work in other sites.

They have the same version of IE as I have.  And there were no errors being reported before you clicked this button.

Has anyone experienced this before?  (I'm not sure what other information would be useful - sorry).

Edit.

I don't think it's worth posting the entire source (it's pretty big) - plus I have looked through and despite finding 1 div without a closing div tag, I have fixed that and the error still occurs.

The filter button is calling javascript:

```
onLoadPage = function(pageNo) {

var url = '<%= Url.Action("List", new { Controller = "Thing", Domain = "Thing" }) %>?page=' + pageNo +
        '&giftoffering=' + encodeURIComponent($("#GiftOffering_Id").val()) +          
....................;

        $.post(url,  $("#list_form").serialize(), function(data) {
            $("#list_holder").html(data);
        });

};
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#results_list").standardGrid();
    });
```

The ..... section is where it grabs values from the form to pass it into the action.

And again this works on my local pc (same version of IE) but not this guy's laptop :(

The IE8 compatibility view has - I believe - now been fully switched off.

I can also see that it is replacing the URL in the browser window with the action name - which kind of explains why it is only returning the view, not the full content.  However I don't understand why the url is changing.  In this browser only?!!!

Update - have used the WAVE toolbar in firefox to check for invalid html, and the only thing it complains about now is a couple of form labels not associated to a control properly.  But they're loaded fne first time around so I don't think it's them.

So the page loads fine, it's only on the load of the results - and only on this person's laptop (not when I test the same files and database locally).

Unless it could potentially be something related to his Internet Explorer security settings or something.  As it works fine on my PC with the same files.

Comment: Could you post some code please?

Comment: The only reason I didn't was I wasn't sure which code to post :) (system is massive) - more after ideas why it would be working locally in the same version of IE8 and not working on someone's laptop.  Though I can appreciate code would help!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a wild guess at compatibility view in IE8 being on when it shouldn't be.

Other than that we need code as @LordCover has suggested.

Comment: Your wild guess might be right - I'm getting the user to turn off the compatibility view to see what happens.  I assume that kicks in when the syntax on the page isn't quite right?  ie. I'm missing a closing something.

Comment: So I have tried turning off the compatibility view - but as soon as I click the filter button it renders the view and I can see the compatibility view mode icon next to the refresh icon (next to the address).  I did find a div that had a missing closing div - but even after fixing that and clearing temporary internet files and restarting the browser a few times the same thing is still happening.

Comment: Oh - turns out apart from the menu link to compatibility view options there's also a setting here: Internet Options> Advanced> Browsing> uncheck "Automatically recover from
page layout errors with Compatibility View."  - Although unticking this running the page again, just shows the same error.  I have checked the web page syntax rendered and it looks fine, its only when it should be loading up the partial view and updating part of the page it only loads the partial view so gets errors because its missing references to css and js (because it's not the whole page).

Comment: @Jen - interesting; I didn't know about that setting for IE.  Yeah it's definitely pointing to slightly dodgy Html; a bit part of a browser's compliance with the Html spec is all about how it handles errors rather than whether it renders correct Html correctly; that's what the Acid Test is all about.

Comment: What's annoying is that using the WAVE toolbar in Firefox to look at the html - the only thing it complains about is a couple of form labels not associated to a control - and they are on the initial load of the page which is displayed correctly.  So the page loads fine - its only when you try to refresh the div with the result list that it falls apart.

Comment: @Jen - Hi; here's a left-field idea.  Can you mock up an html page with the html as it would be with this dynamically loaded element in it, then load it in that browser on that machine - it has to be identical mind you.

Answer (score 0):

> Similar functionality in an earlier version was also set up as a different site on the same machine - and that works fine in IE

1.Could be cache problem, try to disable browser cache
2. Markup problem, check div id's and closing tags.

Comment: Tried clearing the cache (and deleting temporary internet files) but no luck.  Will check the markup and look for missing closing tags thanks.